# Rails random number always the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a random number. I have an Account table and I need to assign a random account inside of each but when I save all the data, I notice all the records have the same random number (1).

I have only 2 accounts. I tested with 10.times do... and it seems to works fine, but I'm not sure why this isn't working, any ideas?

```
  data = []
  accounts = Account.all
  searches.each do 
      data << SearchesResult.new({
          :account_id => accounts[rand(accounts.count)]
      })
  end
  SearchesResult.import data
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign to a random account, or assign a random account number?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting an Account object and passing that in as :account_id.  You probably want

```
  data << SearchesResult.new({
      :account_id => accounts[rand(accounts.count)].id
  })
```

or, as mckeed says,

```
  data << SearchesResult.new({
      :account => accounts[rand(accounts.count)]
  })
```

Comment: or `:account => accounts[rand(accounts.count)]`